# Using finalize() With The Decorator Pattern

Tags: java, decorator, backwards-compatibility

I have a design issue I am trying to resolve. In short, is it ok to use `finalize()` to release `private static` resources that pertain only to that object, and are only of use for as long as that object lives? Details follow...

First here are the constraints:

1. I am using the decorator pattern to encapsulate a type (`X`) that I
   didn't write
2. `X` is **`final`** so subclassing it is out of the question.
3. I have a method in the wrapper, say `x()`, that at any time will
   return the underlying `X instance`
4. The reason for `x()` is that the wrapper type needs to be
   interchangeably compatible with existing API's that expect an `X`
   parameter
5. The wrapper has a constructor that takes an `X` instance as a
   parameter. It then sets its encapsulated `X` object to be this
   instance.

The problem:

I want to add some functionality/data in the wrapper, **BUT** have it preserved. By this I mean, when the wrapper is 'unwrapped' to `X`, it can then be 'rewrapped' to the wrapper at some other point in the code, and hey presto, the extra data is restored even though it is not carried in the underlying `X`.

My thoughts so far:

If I create a static map in the wrapper class where the key is a unique `X` id, and the value is this extra data in some structure, then I can retrieve it inside the `rewrap(X x)` method let's say.

I won't use the wrapper or `X` object as the key in the map as this will stop it ever possibly being GC'd (unless explicitly removed from the map), so instead we'll use unique hashcodes.

Whilst this seems OK in principle, the issue is when to delete this extra data from the static map. In this case can we permit an implementation of finalize():

```
finalize(){
   map.remove(wrapperKey);
}
```

Here's my justification... We all know relying on finalize() is a bad idea to release resources in general, but here the resources in question pertain directly to the object. There is no reference to external resources, and so we need these internal resources until the wrapper object itself is GC'd, at which point we just delete the resources mapping.

The worst case scenario would be not worry about deleting these static mappings that are redundant, as this results in memory leaks.

I can't think of any other way to achieve this functionality and preserve the backwards compatibility with existing APIs:

```
public void foo(Wrapper wrapper){
  bar(wrapper.x());
}
public void bar(X instance){...}
```

So that's the problem, any alternative approaches or opinions?

Many thanks

**EDIT:**
After further research I thought I would update this question as similar situations may be prime candidates for [weak references](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you explicitly call Wrapper.x every time you need access to the X instance, couldn't you add a cleanup method to Wrapper and explicitly call that before getting rid of the Wrapper object?

The cleanup method could be called from *finalize* too, to ensure that it gets cleaned up if it hasn't been called explicitly. This would give you the best of two worlds, as it would give you a greater chance of reducing memory leaks if the Wrapper is used incorrectly.

```
void someRandomMethod() {
    Wrapper someWrapperINeed = new Wrapper(new X(blah, blah blah));
    foo(someWrapperINeed);
    someWrapperINeed.clean();

    // Instead of foo(new Wrapper(new X(blah, blah, blah));
}

// Or foo can call clean if the wrapper will never be needed after its invocation
void foo(Wrapper w) {
    bar(w.x());
    w.clean();
}
```

Edit: Added code sample!

Comment: I've just edited the question because I lacked some clarity, sorry for that. The extra data is directly associated with the X instance, so it needs to be preserved in case that unwrapped X instance is later rewrapped. I can't dispose of the extra data in x() therefore.

Comment: Is the wrapperKey related to the X instance? So that you can lookup the extra data and recreate Wrapper objects from knowing the X? In that case, why aren't you using the X objects as keys directly? And how could you delete the additional data from the Wrapper's finalize method at all? Then you would likely lose the data before recreating a Wrapper.

Comment: That's an excellent point. The key would need to pertain directly to X, as the wrappers are disposable and recreated whenever. The deleting of this extra data would need to be done in X's finalize in this case, because the wrapper would not know whether it was the last time X would be wrapped. Hmmm... Any thoughts on an alternative approach to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Is it only the "legacy" code that has any control over when the X is disposed of? Is there some kind of event you could listen to, to be able to dispose of the data in the wrapper at an appropriate time? Could the classes which require the X instances be sub-classed?

Comment: The wrapper is part of a layer/plug in that sits on top of the existing API. There aren't any callbacks to hook in to frustratingly... It looks increasing like the best I can do is store the extra data inside the wrapper and not preserve it. Either that or make it the clients responsibility to dispose of extra data.. but that's perhaps a bit unfriendly?

Comment: It's not uncommon to require that programmers call a clean-up function when they're done with some component in a library. This is more common in other languages, especially languages that don't have a garbage collector, and it's almost always the case with native code wrappers in Java. It should be described in the class's documentation (javadoc).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The two options I have are only store the extra data in the wrapper 'locally' and just dispose of it when necessary, or as you say, make it the clients responsibility. Will ponder this